# XSL 1.0 How to replace two different things in a string

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I've got a string that could have line breaks and apostrophes. I need to do a replace for both. I have the following xsl code:

```
<xsl:call-template name="replaceapostrophes">
<xsl:with-param name="string">
    <xsl:call-template name="replacelinefeeds">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="hl7:text/hl7:paragraph"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>

    <!-- template for replacing line feeds with <br> tags for page display -->
<xsl:template name="replacelinefeeds">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($string,'&#10;')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string,'&#10;')"/>
            <br/>
            <xsl:call-template name="replacelinefeeds">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string,'&#10;')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<!-- template for replacing html encoded apostrophes for page display -->
<xsl:template name="replaceapostrophes">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($string, '&amp;#39;')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string,'&amp;#39;')"/>'<xsl:call-template name="replaceapostrophes">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string,'&amp;#39;')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This is the xml code:

```
<text>
  <paragraph>Adding apostrophe to the patient&amp;#39;s instructions
  and checking for a second line</paragraph>
</text>
```

However, when this runs, I'm getting the apostrophe accounted for, but not the line breaks.

```
Adding apostrophe to the patient's instructions and checking for a second line
```

rather than

```
Adding apostrophe to the patient's instructions
and checking for a second line
```

It does work fine if there's one or the other but not both in the same string.

Is there a different way I need to do these?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it the other way around (replace apostrophes first, then line breaks).

Basically you are putting an HTML `<br/>` element into your variable, and then taking its text value to replace the apostrophes , which removes the line break again.

Answer (score 1):

Use the templates the other way round, i.e. first replace the apostrophes, then the line feeds. And make sure for the result of the replacement of line feeds you use `xsl:copy-of` and not `xsl:value-of` when you output it, as otherwise the `br` elements will be lost. So in case you have `<xsl:variable name="text"><xsl:call-template name="replacelinefeeds">..</xsl:call-template></xsl:variable>`, make sure you use `<xsl:copy-of select="$text"/>`.